# New admob in Android Studio

Tags: android

I'm trying to figure out how to add the new admob to my app in Android Studio. Here are a couple of questions:

1 How and where to I find out what number or version to add to the dependencies in build.gradle.  I found two tutorials referencing the below but no explanation:
- com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.4.52 another one uses
- com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23

Comment: gradle will tell you if you have an out of date version number

Comment: Hi thereSo what version do I use, I just need some help understanding this as I'me new to android studio and it's the first time I'm hearing about gradle.